# How can I Iterate over each file in a directory using ET.parse function

Tags: xml, loops, parsing, for-loop, iterator

When i run the code below, i can only successfully parse one xml file (using the designated xslt file) from my source folder ( denoted by "myfilepath" below). 
This is despite the fact that there are 10 xml files in this source folder.

I have tried both os.dir and glob but neither seems to successfully loop through each xml file in the folder

Any help will be GREATLY APPRECIATED!

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import pandas as pd
import glob 

xml_path = (/"myfilepath")
xslt = (/"myfilepath/results_stylesheet.xsl")


#routine to define pathway to open multiple files

xml_files = glob.glob(xml_path + "/*.xml")
cntr = 1

#perform our parsing operations on all xml files in the named xml_file path above 
for file in xml_files:

            with open(xml_files, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as content:  
                data = open(xslt)
                xslt_content = data.read()
                xslt_root = ET.XML(xslt_content)
                transform = ET.XSLT(xslt_root)
                for file in xml_files:
                    dom = ET.parse(content)
                    result = transform(dom)

with open("Parsed" + str(cntr) + '.csv','w')as outputfile:
    outputfile.write(str(result))
    outputfile.close()
    cntr +=1
```

I would like the code to loop through each xml file in the source folder, parse using the xslt stylesheet and then save the parsed file to a new csv file in the same folder as the source folder.
I would like each parsed file to have a naming convention like "Parsed1.csv", "Parsed2.csv" etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your paste the intentation looks wrong. Like the output writing is outside the for loop of xml_files.